# AWS SSM sessions manager doesn't work for private instances with NACL configured

Tags: aws-ssm

I am unable to use AWS SSM sessions manager for secure login to my private instances with NACL rules applied. Whereas AWS SSM works if I update NACL rules open To public(0.0.0.0/0).I want my private instances to be secure and not have open connections in NACL.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

> I want my private instances to be secure and not have open connections

To use AWS SSM in a completely private subnet that has no inbound or outbound access to the internet, you need to use VPC endpoints. Follow the steps described in [the AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-systems-manager-vpc-endpoints/) to do this:

> Amazon EC2 instances must be registered as managed instances to be
> managed with AWS Systems Manager. Follow these steps:
>
> 1. Verify that SSM Agent is installed on the instance.
> 2. Create an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) instance profile for Systems Manager. You can create a new role, or add the needed
>    permissions to an existing role.
> 3. Attach the IAM role to your private EC2 instance.
> 4. Open the Amazon EC2 console, and then select your instance. On the Description tab, note the VPC ID and Subnet ID.
> 5. Create a VPC endpoint for Systems Manager. For Service Name, select com.amazonaws.[region].ssm (for example, com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ssm).
>    For a full list of Region codes, see Available Regions. For VPC,
>    choose the VPC ID for your instance. For Subnets, choose a Subnet ID
>    in your VPC. For high availability, choose at least two subnets from
>    different Availability Zones within the Region. Note: If you have more
>    than one subnet in the same Availability Zone, you don't need to
>    create VPC endpoints for the extra subnets. Any other subnets within
>    the same Availability Zone can access and use the interface. For
>    Enable DNS name, select Enable for this endpoint. For more
>    information, see Private DNS for interface endpoints. For Security
>    group, select an existing security group, or create a new one. The
>    security group must allow inbound HTTPS (port 443) traffic from the
>    resources in your VPC that communicate with the service. If you
>    created a new security group, open the VPC console, choose Security
>    Groups, and then select the new security group. On the Inbound rules
>    tab, choose Edit inbound rules. Add a rule with the following details,
>    and then choose Save rules: For Type, choose HTTPS. For Source, choose
>    your VPC CIDR. For advanced configuration, you can allow specific
>    subnets' CIDR used by your EC2 instances. Note the Security group ID.
>    You'll use this ID with the other endpoints. Optional: For advanced
>    setup, create policies for VPC interface endpoints for AWS Systems
>    Manager. Repeat step 5 with the following change:
> 6. For Service Name, select com.amazonaws.[region].ec2messages.
> 7. Repeat step 5 with the following change: For Service Name, select com.amazonaws.[region].ssmmessages. You must do this if you want to
>    use Session Manager.
>
> After the three endpoints are created, your instance appears in
> Managed Instances, and can be managed using Systems Manager.